# How to right align matrix

Tags: align, matrices

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
 \mathbf{J}_{f}
 = \begin{bmatrix}
   -2 x \sin\left(y\right) ^{2} & -2x^{2}\sin\left(y\right) \cos\left(y\right) &  0
   \\
   \sin\left(y\right)  & x \cos\left(y\right)  & 0
   \\
   2x & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix} 
.\end{align*}
```

How do I right align the matrix, so that for example in the first column the `sin(y)` aligns with `-2` and not in the middle.

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean “left align”?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `mathtools` provided `bmatrix*`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads amsmath

\begin{document}

You can get left alignment
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{J}_{f} =
\begin{bmatrix*}[l]
  -2 x \sin(y) ^{2} & -2x^{2}\sin(y) \cos(y) &  0
  \\
  \sin(y)  & x \cos(y)  & 0
  \\
  2x & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix*}.
\end{equation*}
or, alternatively, right alignment
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{J}_{f} =
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  -2 x \sin(y) ^{2} & -2x^{2}\sin(y) \cos(y) &  0
  \\
  \sin(y)  & x \cos(y)  & 0
  \\
  2x & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix*}.
\end{equation*}
but I find neither to be prettier than with the standard
center alignment
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{J}_{f} =
\begin{bmatrix}
  -2 x \sin(y) ^{2} & -2x^{2}\sin(y) \cos(y) &  0
  \\
  \sin(y)  & x \cos(y)  & 0
  \\
  2x & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A few unrelated comments. Avoid `\left` and `\right` in that context: they only add undesired spacing. Also `align` should be used for several equations to be aligned.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 3):

Right alignment can be obtained using `array` environment (even without `amsmath`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Right alignment can be obtained using \verb|array| environment.
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{J}_{f} =\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
-2 x \sin(y) ^{2}&-2x^{2}\sin(y) \cos(y) &  0   \\
\sin(y)  & x \cos(y)  & 0   \\
2x & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right].
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you the combination with `\left[` and `\begin{array}` then there are some white space occurs between `square brackets` and `array`, so `\begin{bmatrix}` is the correct one...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Oh, I see that now. I have heard that `array` environment can be highly customized. Maybe some negative space `\!` should be used ???

Comment: Hopefully the correct format is (if you are using `array`) `\left[\begin{array}{@{}...@{}}`

Comment: MadyYuvi : I did not know this difference (some white space) between the two commands: (1) \begin{bmatrix} and (2) the combo of \left[ and \begin{array} until I read your reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Also the old package `spalign` package provides to have right/center/left align matrix. In fact you can see that is possible to obtain the same ouptut of the other users.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{spalign}
\usepackage{parskip}


\begin{document}
Center option
\[\mathbf{J}_{f}=\spaligndelims{[}{]}
\spalignmat[c]{-2x\sin(y)^{2} -2x^{2}\sin(y)\cos(y)  0; \sin(y) x\cos(y) 0; 2x 0 0} 
.\]
Left option 
\[\mathbf{J}_{f}=\spaligndelims{[}{]}
\spalignmat[l]{-2x\sin(y)^{2} -2x^{2}\sin(y)\cos(y)  0; \sin(y) x\cos(y) 0; 2x 0 0} 
.\]
Right option
\[\mathbf{J}_{f}=\spaligndelims{[}{]}
\spalignmat[r]{-2x\sin(y)^{2} -2x^{2}\sin(y)\cos(y)  0; \sin(y) x\cos(y) 0; 2x 0 0} 
.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: First time, I came to know about `spalign.sty`...thanks, and hope all is well....

Comment: @MadyYuvi Dear friend, from time to time I use old packages that are forgotten but sometimes they reduce LaTeX code by a lot. I always wish you and your family well.

Answer (score 1):

The environment `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` has (among other features) keys `r` and `l` for the horizontal alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

You can get left alignment
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{J}_{f} =
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[l]
  -2 x \sin(y) ^{2} & -2x^{2}\sin(y) \cos(y) &  0
  \\
  \sin(y)  & x \cos(y)  & 0
  \\
  2x & 0 & 0
\end{bNiceMatrix}.
\end{equation*}
or, alternatively, right alignment
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{J}_{f} =
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[r]
  -2 x \sin(y) ^{2} & -2x^{2}\sin(y) \cos(y) &  0
  \\
  \sin(y)  & x \cos(y)  & 0
  \\
  2x & 0 & 0
\end{bNiceMatrix}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]